# Shibboleth, IIS 7.5, Tomcat

Tags: iis, shibboleth

I am trying to set up Shibboleth SP on a Server 2008 R2/ IIS 7.5 machine.

IIS throws the following error when browsing to localhost:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\opt\shibboleth-sp\lib64\shibboleth\isapi_shib.dll" failed
```

I'm assuming that this is because IIS does not have permissions to get to that dll file, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
I went to the C:\opt folder and added permissions for the IIS_USRS group for the shibboleth-sp folder, but still it didn't work.  Is there another user that I have to give permission to because it's using IIS 6 Compatibility Mode?

Is there anything else that I should be checking besides for based on this error besides for the folder permissions?

Comment: Do you have a reference or set of instructions you are following? The installer seems like it sets things up fairly easily: http://www.upenn.edu/computing/weblogin/shibboleth/setup/IIS7.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured this out a little while ago and never got the chance to post back now.

Originally, I installed the 64-bit version/ used the 64-bit version DLL and got the 500 error.
Due to the app that I was protecting with Shibboleth, I had to change the application pool to allow 32-bit DLL's.  As far as I can tell, enabling 32-bit DLL's effectively disables 64-bit DLL's.  Once I tried the 32-bit DLL (by installing the 64 bit version, but running as 32 bit) the installation went well.